Mechatronics/Electrical Engineering question
If I wanted to determine stall torque on a DC motor, how would I do that? If I'm referencing the data sheet that states: at 3 VDC, measured 150 mA @ 120 RPM no-load, and 1.1 Amps when stalled.
Would I have to factor in the 3 V voltage supply?
Motor: DC Gearbox Motor - "TT Motor" - 200RPM - 3 to 6VDC

The information presented so far doesn't provide any torques.  Can you post datasheet?   Need to look for either a motor parameter (torque/amp) or the max torque, which for DC motor happens at stall.   Otherwise you can try to measure with a lever arm attached to shaft, but be prepared to take lots of measurements at different shaft angles.

Yes, of course, here’s the datasheet, this is the only information I’ve been given; https://www.adafruit.com/product/3777

@jack101 If an answer solved your problem its considered good practice to mark it as accepted

The easy answer is to read the datasheet:
Technical Details

Rated Voltage: 3~6V
Continuous No-Load Current: 150mA +/- 10% Min.
Operating Speed (3V): 90+/- 10% RPM
Min. Operating Speed (6V): 200+/- 10% RPM
Stall Torque (3V): 0.4kg.cm
Stall Torque (6V): 0.8kg.cm

https://www.adafruit.com/product/3777
